# Subscribe to changes in MySQL database without polling

Tags: mysql, node.js, redis, publish-subscribe

I have a MySQL database that is updated by a different application which I want to subscribe to for changes from my node.js server. Is it possible to monitor the database for any updates without long polling all the rows/columns for any changes to their value?

One potential solution I have seen is to use redis to subscribe to the database to listen for any changes and then it informs my client (which will be my server in this case). How do I subscribe redis to MySQL database, if this is possible?

Comment: I edited the title to clarify the key constraint and made the question body clearer as well. I also removed an overly-general tag to restrict it to answerers who can help.

Comment: If it's an option, Postgres does support LISTEN and NOTIFY statements which do exactly what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not just add an `updated` column to your tables?

You could add **`ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`** on the column, which would automatically store the current time every time that row was updated. The rule is applied to the database itself, so you don't need to update any other clients which use the database, it will work automatically.

Any client could then make queries based on the last time it checked for updates. You just need to `SELECT` rows based on its `updated` field.

You're only checking one column that way, and its quite a fast query.

You could index the datetime field too, [apperently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087767/creating-an-index-on-a-timestamp-to-optimize-query). That would probably make the queries very fast indeed.

Comment: I should add, I don't believe you can 'listen' to MySQL updates. If you could, you would need to perform computations on every single update... even unimportant ones. I considered linking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884478/can-php-listen-for-a-mysql-database-change-or-update-thinking-real-time-liv but I didn't care for the answers. Triggers might work, but you would still probably need to poll for updates in some way regardless

Comment: thanks!, I am not sure if I am doing this the right way but if on MYSQL workbench when creating the time-stamp field I check the unique index box will that ensure the datetime field gets indexed?

Comment: Don't use a unique index: if two records are created at the same timestamp (twice in the same second for example, which is quite likely) it will reject one of the records. You have to add an index via the Indexes tab in MySQL Workbench. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor-indexes-tab.html . I believe you just tick the column and choose 'apply' to add an index for the `updated` field