# How to generate notifications from MySQL table updates?

Tags: mysql, real-time

I have a full stack app that uses React, Node.js, Express, and MySQL. I want the react app to respond to database updates similar to Firebase: When data changes, I want a real-time notification sent to my app.

I want to use stock MySQL (no plugins), so that I can use AWS RDB or whatever.

I will use socket.io to push the real-time notifications to the web app.

To avoid off-target responses, I'll summarize various approaches that are not what I am looking for:

1. The server could poll, or each client could poll. (Not real-time, but included for completeness. When I search, polling is the only solution I find.)
2. Write a wrapper that handles all MySQL updates, handles subscriptions, and sends the notifications. This is a complicated component that adds complexity. Firebase is popular because it both increases performance and reduces complexity. I like Firebase a lot but want to do the same thing with MySQL.
3. Use Firebase to handle the real-time notifications. The MySQL wrapper could use Firebase to handle the subscriptions and notifications, but there is still the problem of triggering the notifications in the first place. Also, I don't want to use Firebase. (For example, my application needs to run in an air-gapped environment.)

The question: Using a stock MySQL database, when a table changes, can a notification server discover the change in real-time (no polling), so that it can send notifications?

Comment: Short answer: No, stock MySQL does not do this. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75365342/20860

Comment: @BillKarwin, thanks for your answer. You describes polling (#1 above), adding a wrapper (#2 above), and also "Change Data Capture" using Debezium. That third choice is the kind of thing I want. I was hoping for a solution that doesn't require running 4 additional containers and writing a thousand lines of configuration files. Anybody else have a suggestion?

Comment: I see https://github.com/zendesk/maxwell is an alternative to Debezium.

Comment: Simply put, MySQL does not allow sending messages _from_ the database to the outside world.  Can you "send" the notification _before_ writing to the db?

Comment: @RickJames, sending the notification before writing is my #2 above. I want something that works without the application developer needing to be proactive. (Otherwise, it's too much work and too error prone.)

Comment: Can you force all actions to go through a Stored Routine (or use a Trigger) which records the activity in a table.  Then have another process that checks that table and sends out whatever is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach that works is to listen to the binary logs. This way, any change to the database will be communicated in real-time. The consumer of the binary logs can then publish this information in a number of ways. A common choice is to feed a stream of events to Apache Kafka.

Debezium, Maxwell, and NiFi work this way.