# How to subscribe to changes in a database

Tags: javascript, sql, database, publish-subscribe

I am creating an api that utilizes the database in a publish subscribe way. What I essentially want is some kind of subscription relationship where I have a function that analyses the query or preferably the result of the query, and execute a code block depending on the result. I tried researching the subject and all I found was RxJS and Rx-Java that only deal with asynchronous programming.

What I essentially want is something that looks like this.

```
const query = 'update data (id, name) values (?,?)'
const params = [1, 'data']

function foo (query, params) {
    const callback = async () => {
        const result = await DB.exec(query, params);
    }
    return callback; 
}

function Observe(callback) {
    //emit changes in the database
    callback();
}

Observe (foo(query, params))
```

Other solutions include polling the updated at field as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044753/subscribe-to-changes-in-mysql-database-without-polling) however such solution still needs a solution to analyze changes, and will not work with create and delete queries.

The third solution is to use a ready ORM

```
function update(model, {data: data}){
    model.update({data: data});
    //emit changes here
}
```

however this will not work with complex queries and will not automatically detect changes in the table schema itself.

what I am looking for is some material that tackle a similar problem or any documentation about how sql is compiled.

**I say SQL but I will also work with other types of databases.*

Comment: What specific SQL database are you using? MySQL doesn't have any way to subscribe to changes, but maybe some other databases do.

Comment: Do you have to do it through a database? We use Beanstalk queues for this.

Comment: @Barmar I am not using any specific sql database. however I would prefer if the solution is database independent. however I have not heard of beanstalks before. I will look check that out.


*edit: you seem to be talking about Elastic Beanstalk. I though it was an aws solution similar to firebase but more extensive and offer much control and scalability.